# How to Run Multiples URLs in Requests from a File

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrap multiples websites from URLs in a txt file. There's one url per line.

my code is:

```
Import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

file = open('url.txt', 'r')
filelines = file.readline()
urllist = requests.get(filelines)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllist.content, "html.parser")
content = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "title-main-info"})
print content
```

But it prints only the last url content (last line). What i'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It should work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('url.txt', 'r') as f:
    for links in f.readlines():
        urllist= requests.get(links.strip())
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urllist.content, "html.parser")
        content = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "title-main-info"})
        print content
```

Comment: I should have considered that in the first place. Thanks. Gonna edit it.

Comment: @Jodmoreira, If it works, don't forget to mark this as an answer.